# Another Subset sum problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

Verify that (S = {83, 88, 93, 67, 57, 89, 78, 51, 95, 98, 69, 49}, t = 492) is a positive instance of Susbset Sum.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ consists of $12$ numbers. Hence it has $2^{12} = 4096$ subsets.

You can write a computer program that goes over all subsets, sums each of them, and determines whether the sum is $492$, in which case it prints the subset.